# What mailer does cron use to send mail?

Tags: centos, cron, centos6, sendmail

I am trying to debug an issue with cron not sending mail on a Centos 6 box that I did not configure. How can I determine which mailer cron is using to send mail? The crontab man page has this to say, in part:

> In  addition  to  LOGNAME,  HOME,  and SHELL, cron(8) will look at MAILTO if it has any reason to send mail as a
>   result of running commands in "this" crontab.  If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to the user so
>   named.   If  MAILTO is defined but empty (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent.  Otherwise mail is sent to the owner
>   of the crontab.  *This option is useful if you decide on /bin/mail instead of /usr/lib/sendmail  as  your  mailer
>   when  you  install cron -- /bin/mail doesn´t do aliasing, and UUCP usually doesn´t read its mail.*

The part with asterisks is the part that has me wondering "Well, is it sendmail or mail?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google shows me that `/etc/sysconfig/crond` is the file that defines what mailer is used by cron.

Comment: My Google-fu is apparently terrible because I spent a good amount of time looking for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

According to the man page for cron(8) (the daemon that actually sends the message):

```
   -m     This  option  allows you to specify a shell command string to use for 
          sending cron mail output instead of sendmail(8).  This command must 
          accept a fully formatted mail message (with headers) on stdin and send
          it as a mail message to the recipients specified in the mail headers.
```

That leads me to believe that it's using sendmail by default.  Let's verify with strace:

Set up a cron job that'll generate email:

```
user@host1 ~:
$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
user@host1 ~:
$ crontab -l
MAILTO=example@example.com
*/5 * * * * echo "testing"
```

Now find the process ID for crond:

```
user@host1 ~:
$ ps auxww | grep crond
root      9684  0.0  0.0 117280  1296 ?        Ss   Jul22   0:17 crond
user     36344  0.0  0.0 103240   884 pts/2    S+   23:01   0:00 grep crond
```

Attach to the crond process with strace, looking for process related activity.  As strace writes to stderr
I've redirected it to stdout and grepped for 'mail':

```
root@host1 ~:
# strace -fp 9684 -s 1024 -e trace=process 2>&1 | grep mail
[pid 36204] execve("/usr/sbin/sendmail", ["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-FCronDaemon", "-i", "-odi", "-oem", "-oi", "-t", "-f", "root"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
^C
```

Yep, it's sendmail.

Comment: On the system you tested.

Comment: Right, which is CentOS as tagged on this question, in its default configuration.

Comment: I know I'm banging a tired drum here, but it's a configurable parameter, and the question involved a system that the asker did not set up. The mailer could have been previously changed from the default, for the system in question. The asker knows the default.

Comment: Right but in it's default configuration, there is nothing referencing mail in the config file (minus comments, the entire content is `CRONDARGS=`).  The fact that it's configurable is why I included the steps to verify for one's self.

Comment: Seems to be CentOS/RHEL specific. On Ubuntu 20.04 I get "/usr/sbin/cron: invalid option -- 'm'"