# CentOS 7 sending e-mail crons while sendmail is not installed

Tags: centos, cron, sendmail

### Background

I have configured my crontab to send me emails that way

```
MAILTO=myemail@company.com
...
```

And I am receiving the e-mail in `myemail@company.com`'s inbox through the company SMTP server without having to configure anyting. (They do not require authentication if you send an e-mail from the company's network a company e-mail address).

The server is linked to our Windows active directory through Kerberos and Samba, if this is of any help to diagnose the issue.

### The issue

I want to edit the e-mail settings because I need to authenticate to the SMTP to be able to send the cron e-mails on non-company e-mails.

### What I've tried already

After a quick look on google, I've found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/632250/what-mailer-does-cron-use-to-send-mail/632265). Problem: Sendmail is not installed on the server and there is nothing related to e-mail configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/crond`.

What else can I do to figure out what is used to send e-mails from crond and how to configure it ?

Comment: maybe postfix ? have you an `/etc/postfix` directory ?

Comment: I do have postfix installed, does crond falls back to postfix if sendmail is not installed ?

Comment: @NoahBoegli, both `sendmail` and `postfix` are MTA so they can deliver mail. If you set `postfix` not to listen it can be used to deliver locally and forward the mail.

Comment: The source code of the message may have `Received` headers pointing the name of the mail transfer agent. Have you looked into it?

Comment: I hadn't thought of looking in here. It says postifx. Thanks to all of you for helping me figuring this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

Looking into the headers of the e-mail, there was a small line mentionning postfix.

Furthermore, I could have directly thought of looking for postfix when I found out that sendmail was not installed.

Conclusion: Next time I'll double check e-mail headers before posting.

Comment: This is a typical RTFM (read the fine mail) solution. +1